# Proving that $\sum (-1)^{n+1} n^{-z}$ defines an analytic function in $Re z>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

I want to show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-z}$ converges to an analytic function for $\Re z>0$.

For $\Re z>1$ the terms are dominated by $n^{-x}$ so that we have absolute and uniform convergence on compact sets, and by Weierstrass' theorem the sum is analytic there. For $\Re z \leq 1$ however I can't show absolute convergence. I tried splitting into real and imaginary parts:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-z}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-x}\cos(-y \ln n)+i\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-x}\sin(-y \ln n),$$
and showing convergence for both using Leibniz's test (or even the more general Dirichlet's test) without success.

I'd love to have any hints about how to do this right.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}=\frac{1}{1^s}+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}..-\frac{2}{2^s}-\frac{2}{4^s}-\frac{2}{6^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$

Comment: @Ethan I believe this representation holds only for $\Re z>1$, where $\zeta$ has its series representation.

Comment: @user1337 The equality stated by Ethan indeed holds for $\mathrm{Re}\,z>0$. I don't think it helps here, though: proving the required properties of $\zeta$ is probably harder than dealing with the alternating sum directly.

Comment: In the presence of $(-1)^{n+1}$ it is natural to try pairing the terms into $b_k=(2k)^{-s}-(2k+1)^{-s}$. Since the terms of original series go to zero, it converges iff $\sum b_k$ converges. You may be able to get a good estimate for $|b_k|$.

Comment: See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436543/interval-of-convergence-of-sum-n-exp-x-sqrt-n/436555#436555). 
In this case $a_n=(−1)^n,\, \lambda_n= \log n $ so $A=0$.

Comment: A [derivation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221994/riemann-zeta-function-manipulation/222588#222588) using the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$\frac1{n^s}-\frac1{(n+1)^s}=s\int\limits_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{s+1}}$$

and now, putting $\,s=\sigma+it\;,\;\;\sigma\,,\,t\in\Bbb R\,$  and taking into account that $\,\sigma>0\,$:

$$\left|\;\int\limits_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{s+1}}\;\right|\le\int\limits_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\left|x^{s+1}\right|}=\int\limits_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{\sigma+1}}=\left.-\frac1\sigma x^{-\sigma}\right|_n^{n+1}=-\frac1\sigma\left(\frac1{(n+1)^\sigma}-\frac1{n^\sigma}\right)$$

and now observe that

$$-\frac1\sigma\left(\frac1{(n+1)^\sigma}-\frac1{n^\sigma}\right)<\frac1{n^{\sigma+1}}\iff\left[1-\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^\sigma\right]<1\iff\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^\sigma>0$$

and now we just apply the series test...

Comment: Why the last equivalences are true?

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato Good question. Multiplying through by $n^\sigma$ gives the equivalent: $$1-\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\sigma}<\frac{\sigma}{n}$$Which is probably still useful since $n$ is eventually larger than $\sigma$

Comment: @FShrike Why is the inequality true then?

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato We only need it to be true for all large $n$, e.g. $n>\lceil\sigma\rceil$

Comment: @FShrike I was asking why the inequality is true for large $n$. Now I guess it's by Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct proof of the statement using Cauchy's criterion given in [this file](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Etb65536/Dirichlet_Series.pdf).
Let $K_{\epsilon,M} = \{s\in\Bbb C: Re(s)\geq\epsilon,|s|\leq M\}$ be a compact subset of $Re(s)>0$ for $0<\epsilon\ll 1$ and $1\ll M$. Then, $|n^{-s}|\leq n^{-\epsilon}$ for all $s\in K_{\epsilon,M}$. Let $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}$ which is $1$ or $0$. Choose $0<n_1<n_2\in\Bbb N$.

\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{n_1+1}^{n_2}{(-1)^{n+1}\over n^s}\right| & = \left|\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2}{1\over n^s}(S_n-S_{n-1})\right|\\
& = \left|\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2}\left({1\over n^s}-{1\over(n+1)^s}\right)S_n+{S_{n_2}\over(n_2+1)^s}-{S_{n_1}\over(n_1+1)^s}\right|\\
&\leq{1\over(n_1+1)^\epsilon}+{1\over(n_2+1)^\epsilon}+\sum_{n = n_1+1}^{n_2}\left|{1\over n^s}-{1\over(n+1)^s}\right|\\
& \leq {1\over n_1^\epsilon}+{1\over n_2^{\epsilon}}+\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2}\left|\int_n^{n+1}{-s\over x^{s+1}}\ dx\right|\\
& \leq {2\over n_1^{\epsilon}}+\sum_{n=n_1+1}^{n_2}{M\over n^{\epsilon+1}}\\
& \leq {2\over n_1^{\epsilon}}+M\int_{n_1}^{n_2}{1\over x^{1+\epsilon}}\ dx\\
& \leq {2\over n_1^\epsilon}+{M\over\epsilon n_1^{\epsilon}}\to 0,\quad \epsilon\to 0.\\
\end{align*}
Hence by Cauchy criterion, the series converges uniformly on a compact subset $K_{\epsilon,M}$ and as $\epsilon,M$ are arbitrary, we conclude the given series defines a holomorphic function on $Re(s)>0$.

Comment: Isn't $S_n$ either $1$ or $0$?

Comment: @robjohn Corrected.